# How to set cronjob many times a day?

Tags: cron

I'm new with Quartz Cron Jobs, so i'm wondering if it's possible to schedule it this way:
For example i want my job to start each day, each month, each year at those hours/minutes: 
 8:20, 10:20, 12:20, 16:20, 19:20

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since minutes are always the same, this crone job can be achieved pretty easy:

```
0 17 8,10,12,16,19 * * ?
```

Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Day of month, Month, Day of week, Year

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and check [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) it is a utility which helps you to generate cron expressions. It uses `Quartz` open source scheduler.